# How to make parent property not override descendants

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using a css file I got online for a website I'm making, but I'm only embedding some components into the website. This css file uses global styles, and they are overriding all of the global styles on my website. I figured I would just wrap the global styles and make them descendants of a class, and then make that the parent class of my component. Here's an example of what I'm saying

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}

.text {
  color: blue;
}
```

But now all of my `h1` tags on the page end up red. I decided to wrap all the global styles and make it so only the descendants of a certain class would be affected by that style. Here's what the new css looks like

```
.parent-class h1 {
  color: red;
}

.text {
  color: blue;
}
```

and make my html look something like this

```
<h1>This should not be affected by any css</h1>
<div class="parent-class">
  <h1 class="text">Hello</h1>
  <h1>How's it going</h1>
</div>
```

The first part actually works. My top `h1` is not affected by the global css, when it was before.

But here's the problem I'm running into. Before, the `text` class was overriding the global `h1` style, and my `Hello` ended up blue, while my `How's it going` was red. Now that `h1` has been wrapped by a parent, `Hello` is also ending up red.

I know that the parent style appears first in the css file, so I don't think it's a question of what is being rendered first. Also, I know that everything is using classes, and not IDs, so that priority issue isn't occurring either.

I'm guessing that this is occurring because of the `.parent-class h1` now has two rules while `.text` only has one. If that's the case, is there a way to mitigate this problem?

One thing I could do is just wrap the parent around the child, like `.parent-class .text`, but the css file I found online has close to 25,000 lines of code, while the global rules only had about 300, so that would be extremely time consuming, because there's thousands of classes I would need to alter.

Is there another way to fix this problem? If not, is there a way to wrap a parent rule around multiple blocks of code, in a way like this

```
.parent-class {
  .text {
    color:blue; 
  };
  h1 {
    color: red;
  };
}
```

Or is that not possible?

Comment: Have you tried using SCSS/SASS? You can write stuff like your last example there and it will compile it out correctly. Saves a ton of time.

Comment: I think you should use `important`

Comment: Would I have to use `important` on all the children? Because there's thousands of them and that would take a lot of time

Comment: no, please do not use `!important` at all cost. Learn to override CSS the right way

Comment: Just to mention that you have to use **h1** only once in the same page for better markup structure and for SEO purposes. Follow this link for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your second selector is having the same (o higher) specifity by combining it with something else. You can for example add `nth-child(n)` which will not change the behavior of your selector but simply increase its specificity:

```css
.parent-class h1 {
  color: red;
}

.text:nth-child(n) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>This should not be affected by any css</h1>
<div class="parent-class">
  <h1 class="text">Hello</h1>
  <h1>How's it going</h1>
</div>
```

You can also duplicate the class:

```css
.parent-class h1 {
  color: red;
}

.text.text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>This should not be affected by any css</h1>
<div class="parent-class">
  <h1 class="text">Hello</h1>
  <h1>How's it going</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up going with the `.text.text` solution. I just used regex to add it to each class. Thanks so much for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update multiple stylesheet rules loaded from another source, you can use the [CSSStyleSheet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) to delete and insert rules:

```js
const styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0]
const rules =  Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).map(r => r.cssText) // get the rules texts
rules.forEach(() => styleSheet.deleteRule(0)); // remove the rules from the stylesheet
rules.forEach(cssText => styleSheet.insertRule(`.parent-class ${cssText}`)) // generate new rules with the namespace
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}

.text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>This should not be affected by any css</h1>
<div class="parent-class">
  <h1 class="text">Hello</h1>
  <h1>How's it going</h1>
</div>
```

If you just need to exclude a single case, you can use the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to disable for the `h1` elements with the class `.text`:

```css
.parent-class h1:not(.text) {
  color: red;
}

.text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>This should not be affected by any css</h1>
<div class="parent-class">
  <h1 class="text">Hello</h1>
  <h1>How's it going</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: So the issue with this answer is that there are literally thousands of classes, and this would take a very long time. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

just use !important like this

```
h1 {color: red;}

.text {color: blue !important;}
```

Comment: Please do not show a show him that way of using `!important`, he's still on his way to learn how to proper styling and override from a third party.